# git ignore and folder removal not working

Tags: git, github, push

I am new to git - after initializing a git repo locally, and checking with

```
 ssh -T git@github.com
```

that I am authenticated, I added a folder with +100 MB files in the `.gitignore` file, yet after running 
`git push -f origin master`

that caused an error: `this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB`

then I tried to run

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

but this threw the same error.  I then completely removed the folder from the directory, git added and committed, but I am still unable to push to remote for the same reason.  How is this possible and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `.gitignore`?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `ls -la .` at the root of the repo?

Comment: Have to run, but here are a few tips that may help. Say you have a folder called assets at the root of the repo that you wish to ignore. Add `assets/` to a `.gitignore` file at the root of the repo. If you have committed the assets folder, then have added it to `.gitignore` and wish to remove it from the repo, run `git rm -r --cached assets`, then commit the changes.

Comment: `git` doesn't push files — `git` push commits, and commits contain files. Github checks every commit for large files so you have too. The committed directory is perhaps in a previous commit. Start looking for it in `git log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (specifically `bfg --delete-folders yourBigFolder`), to make sure your repository does not include it in its history.

Then you can push back, because none of your past commit would include such a large folder.